# Web server folder in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

May I know where is the web server folder in the remote desktop of Amazon web service EC2 (Windows instance)? This is where my .php file will reside, where I can point the URL to to upload an image to the server through my iOS app.

Or is it that there are some things which I have to install or configure first?

I am pretty new to this server-app thing, sorry if my question does not make sense/is too basic! Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? Are you using Apache or IIS or nginx or something else?

Comment: the AWS EC2 instance is in Windows and I am using IIS

Comment: I have a folder called C:\inetpub\wwwroot, would that be it? I tried putting a html file in it, but trying to access myPublicDNS/test.html through a browser from another computer does not work.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771280(v=ws.10).aspx will help you see all the sites served through IIS. View properties of the site that interests you and you will see the directory from which that site is served.

Answer (score 0):

The web folder for AWS EC2 window instance, using IIS is indeed in C:/inetpub/wwwroot. My problem was that I haven't open up my security port for http, and therefore couldn't access the php files through my public DNS.